# fb login wont work when uploaded in the web server

Tags: php, facebook, https, uri

I have a website with fb log in. Everything was okay in localhost until I uploaded it in the main server for production(https server). Can someone help me. I already changed the direct URI and domains but still not working. An error will appear:

> Graph returned an error: Unable to load URL: Domain of this URL is not
>       included in the domain of the application. To load this URL, please add all 
>       domains and subdomains to the app settings application domain.

**Note:** I already changed Valid OAuth redirect URIs but still wont work.

Comment: make sure app domains and site url are set correct

Comment: i already did like:

site URL: https://www.sample.world/
App Domains: www.sample.world and sample.world

or i set it wrong?

Comment: What have you set Valid Oauth Redirect URIs to? Does it match the redirect_uri value used in your login dialog call?

Comment: @CBroe yes I did. redirect_uri and login call is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change URL of your facebook application in FB developers API. Go to your app, Settings tab and there is Website section with Site URL field. Change it to whatever url your domain is.

Comment: I already did. still not working. Is there something to do with https://? because i tried it on a test server and localhost it works perfectly well